# button.value is undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

While attempting to make a calculator I found an issue that I was unable to solve. In my script, I told the browser that when a button is clicked, it adds the value of that button to the calculator's display. (for example, if the calculator is currently showing "455", and you click the plus button, the text of the display would turn to "455+", because the value of the plus button is "+").

The issue I am having here is that when I click a button, "undefined" adds instead of the value of that button. how come `button.value` returns undefined instead of the value of the button? What is the problem here?

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const calculator = document.querySelector('form[name = "calculator"]')
  const btns = document.querySelectorAll(`form[name = "calculator"] table tr td`)
  btns.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      calculator.display.value += button.value
    })
  })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head></head>
    </body>
      <!-- Page Contents !-->
      <form name = "calculator">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <input type = "text" name = "display" id = "display" disabled>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type = "button" name = "one" value = "1"></td>
            <td><input type = "button" name = "two" value = "2"></td>
            <td><input type = "button" name = "three" value = "3"></td>
            <td><input type = "button" name = "plus" value = "+"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
      <script src = "script.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Sorry if I am doing something wrong, or breaking any "rules" set in place, I am a new javascript programmer. Thanks!

Comment: A TD does not have a  value. You are attaching the click handler to the cell, not the input

Comment: Your display element is not in a TD, so you have invalid mark up

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're selecting the `<td>`, not the `<input>`. Change your selector to select the buttons.

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(`form[name="calculator"] table tr td input[type="button"]`)
```

Comment: It is not a <button> tag

Comment: s/button/input/?

Comment: It is a `input` tag with the type set to button. I still understand what you are saying though, I inserted an EventListener to a "td" tag and not the button itself, and therefore the value of it remains undefined. Thanks!